# Cordova CTP For Visual Studio add Advertisement for WP8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I'm developing an application in cordova CTP preview for Visual Studio 2013, I want to integrate some advertising but I don't find no way for do that with WP8 apps.
I see they exist admob plugin for cordova but only for IOS/Android.
And I don't know how develop cordova plugins in Cordova CTP preview (the project don't support c# class) and integrate him.

Have you a solution for me or any help for i begin a developpement of admob plugin for WP8.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Now they exist admob plugins for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin project [cordova-admob-pro](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro) supports Android, iOS, WP8 and Windows.

Comment: I know, but when i do this it doesn't exist so i add the plugin in code in WP8 template on cordova.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find information regarding creation of custom plugins on the [official Cordova documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide).

Comment: Hello, I already read this documentation but the structure folders of classic cordova apps and visual studio apps it's not the same. So I think I'm going from blank cordova apps for develop my plugins. Thank you for suggestion.